# Как конвертировать колекциию SQL типа в колекцию PL/SQL типа без циклов?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Пытаюсь конвертировать колекцию SQL типа в колекцию PL/SQL типа (или наоборот).

```
create or replace type arrayforvarchar as table of varchar2(30);
/
```

Пробую как в этом анонимном блоке

```
declare
    type arrayforvarcharplsql is table of varchar2(30);
    var_plsql_array arrayforvarcharplsql;
    var_sql_array arrayforvarchar := arrayforvarchar();
begin
    select cola
    bulk collect into var_plsql_array
    FROM (
        select 'X' as cola from dual
        union all
        select 'Y' as cola from dual);
    --var_sql_array := var_plsql_array
end;
/
```

Но простое присвоение одной коллекции к другой не работает.

Как можно присвоить заначения `var_plsql_array` к `var_sql_array` без использования циклов?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle Converting SQL type to PLSQL collection / Oracle converting one collection type to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64065007) от участника [@sakeesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12271381/sakeesh)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64065007

Answer (score 2):

Нет, без циклов невозможо преобразовать кoллекцию одного типа в коллекцию другого типа.

Пдробнее в подглаве [Assigning Values to Collection Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-7836EEC3-2642-4CF8-AA50-81034855119D):

> **Data Type Compatibility**
> You can assign a collection to a collection variable only if they have the same data type.
> Having the same element type is not enough.

Даже если обе эти коллекции объявлены в PL/SQL, так не будет работать:

```
declare 
    type t1 is table of int;
    type t2 is table of int;
    a t1 := t1 (1);
    b t2;
begin b := a;
end;
/
ORA-06550: line 6, column 12:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

Нет никакой внутренней функции вроде `CAST` для преобразвания кoллекции одного типа к коллекции другого типа. Хотя можно использовать свою собственную функцию чтобы *скрыть цикл*. Воспроизводимый пример:

```
create or replace type arrsql as table of varchar2 (30);
/
var rc refcursor
declare
    type arrpls is table of varchar2(30);
    source arrpls := arrpls ('aaa','bbb','ccc');
    target arrsql;
    function cast (s arrpls, astypeof arrsql) return arrsql is
        t arrsql := arrsql ();
    begin
        t.extend (s.count); 
        for i in 1..s.count loop t(i) := s(i); end loop;
        return t;
    end; 
begin
    target := cast (source, astypeof=>target);
    open :rc for select * from table (target);
end;
/

Result Sequence
------------------------------
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

---

В релизе 20c появится более лаконичня [форма FOR цикла](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-3F424C1F-9C0F-4002-859C-DEAD94FECA82). Тогда преобразование типов коллекций можнно будет написаать проще:

```
declare 
    type arrpls is table of varchar2 (30);
    arr arrpls := arrpls ('aaa','bbb','ccc');
    res arrpls;
begin 
    res := arrpls (for i,v in pairs of arr index i => v);
end;
/
```